# Multiple data-targets for bootstrap tab not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Im trying to make a nav-bar using bootstrap 4 when clicked on a nav-item toggles two divs. In other examples I saw that when using data-target you could add multiple #contents.

```
<a data-target="#tab-content-2, #cmcAGVL">
```

```
<nav>
<div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-home-tab" role="tablist">
<a class="nav-item nav-link active rounded-0" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab-content-1, #cmcVGVL" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">1</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link rounded-0" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab-content-2, #cmcAGVL"  role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria-selected="false">2</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link rounded-0" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab-content-1-1, #cmcIVGVL"  role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Interieur 1</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link rounded-0" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab-content-2-2, #cmcIAGVL" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Interieur 2</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link rounded-0" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab-content-3-3, #cmcBG" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Begane grond</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link rounded-0" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab-content-4-4, #cmcV1" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Eerste verdieping</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link rounded-0" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab-content-5-5, #cmcV2" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Tweede verdieping</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link rounded-0" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tab-content-6-6, #cmcV3" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false">Derde verdieping</a>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="nav-item nav-link rounded-0 dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Geselecteerde opties</button>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" id="insert">
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active home" id="tab-content-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-content-2"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-content-1-1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-content-2-2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-content-3-3"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-content-4-4"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-content-5-5"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-content-6-6"></div>

    <div class="tab-pane active" id="cmcVGVL"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cmcAGVL" >B</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cmcIVGVL">C</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cmcIAGVL">D</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cmcBG">E</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cmcV1">F</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cmcV2">G</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cmcV3">H</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for that?

Comment: Hello, sorry im not often on stackoverflow, I think I fixed it with answer which I commented on below :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the answer in a different thread;

Put the multiple data-targets in a seperate div then put the different tabs in that div

```
  <a class="nav-item nav-link active rounded-0" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#tabs-1" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true">Voorgevel</a>
```

```
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-1" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-content-2"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="cmcIAGVL"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: But this only works with adjacent elements.